# View doesn't load

Tags: codeigniter

I want to ask about view
here I have controller like this: (api.php)

```
public function export_excel() {
    $date = new DateTime($this->input->post('date_fil'));
    $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');
    $user = $this->input->post('sales_name');
    $checked = $this->input->post('cb_month');
    $month = date('m');

    if ((int) $checked == 1) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sales_name', 'Sales Name', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
                'result' => 0,
                'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()
            ]));
            return false;
        }

        $this->db->select('t1.act_id, t2.login, t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes')
                ->from('activity as t1')
                ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('t2.login', $user)
                ->where('MONTH(t1.date_added)', $month);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $data = array('title' => 'Sales Report',
            'user' => $result);

        $this->load->view('report/vw_excel', $data);
        // Selecting data by Date ----------------------------------------------    
    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sales_name', 'Sales Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_fil', 'Date', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
                'result' => 0,
                'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()
            ]));
            return false;
        }

        $this->db->select('t1.act_id, t2.login, t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes')
                ->from('activity as t1')
                ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('t2.login', $user)
                ->where('DATE(t1.date_added)', $curr_date);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $data = array('title' => 'Sales Report',
            'user' => $result);
        $this->load->view('report/vw_excel', $data);
    }
```

and here's the view I want to load it's under folder (report/vw_excel)

```
<body>
  <main>
       <h1>Excel Report</h1>
       <p><a href="<?php echo base_url('report/export_excel') ?>">Export to Excel</a></p>
       <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Sales Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Activity</th>
                      <th>Detail</th>
                      <th>Start Time</th>
                      <th>Finish Time</th>
                      <th>Note</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <?php $i=1; foreach($user as $xuser) { ?>
                 <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_id']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['login']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['cust_name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_type']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_detail']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['date_added']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['date_modified']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_notes']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php $i++; } ?>
            </tbody>
       </table>
  </main>
```

when I call it from other view folder(admin/admin_view)
onsubmit = 'api/export_excel', 
this `"$this->load->view('report/vw_excel', $data);"` wont load the view.

the result are showing in the browser's network, but the view doesn't load.
[network view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmCcB.jpg)

any idea? thanks.

Comment: Does the same thing happen whether you have $checked == 1 or not?

Comment: One thing I have seen from your screenshot - you haven't configured $config['base_url'] as you are getting :: in your links.

Comment: What you should be asking yourself is... Is the script execution even getting to the statements that load your views? So I'd be checking your $_POST values - using var_dump(). Checking your SQL and making sure they are getting results and you are testing for those correctly.. Seeing where the code execution is going... Just standard debug procedures...

Comment: yep it does the same with $checked == 1, my form action is action="<?= site_url('api/export_excel') ?>" , and $config['base_url'] = ' ';

Comment: roger, i'll var_dump that $_post

Comment: Like I said - you need to define $config['base_url'] - having it empty is not good.

Comment: wait sir, I still don't get it. what should i put in base_url? I try with 'localhost/spm/' but it returns something like this http://[::1]/spm/localhost/spm/api/export_excel (double the url). I thought it's related to this current view, since the other views works fine.

Comment: Well can you put that URL into the browser and have it output something? For all I know you have it setup to use ::1 in your URL's...

Answer (score 0):

Do a right click on the screen - inspect element. In the elements panel, select the table that was supposed to be there on screen. Check in the Style panel if the same is not turned off from being displayed for some reason.

You may also check its position (if in case it is visible) on screen for you to be able to diagnose whether the element is actually in screen dimensions.

Comment: thx for reply, well it suppose to jump to the next URL, I trigger it from [::1]/spm/admin when the form is submitted it supposed to go to [::1]/spm/report/vw_excel. but it stay on the current page instead.

Comment: check in the console - is there any javascript error which dose not allow it to go ahead? or .. check if the page is actually getting submitted or what. 
In case of Javascript Error, it might be blocking the page to execute the form submit.
If the same is getting submitted, then you need to verify / check on the form / action URL.

Comment: only one report on console when I submit the form "Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: chrome-"

Comment: Check in the networks tab. See if there is url that comes in? Check the type of button that you assigning as submit. It might be a simple button which wont trigger a submit action.